# Wakanda how to use server method in mobile side?

Tags: wakanda

To bind my data on the mobile side it works like this :

```
getHeros() {
    this.wakanda.getCatalog().then(ds => {
        ds['Superhero'].query({orderBy:"ID desc",pageSize:3}).then(collection => {
            this.favoriteSuperheroes = collection.entities;
        });
    });
}
```

But like this I work directly on the table. I have a method who provide me everything I want on the server side. The Wakand's documentation tells me to do it like this:

```
ds.Company.myDataClassMethod().then(function (result) {

});
```

It won't work, I can't call my method, someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query() on the table works for you while calling dataclasss method does not. A possible cause is that your class method is not set to available to the public.

Please check whether the [scope](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Model/Method/scope.303-1029581.en.html) of the class method is set to "public". 
And test if your method can be accessed directly via REST: 
[127.0.0.1:8081/rest/Company/myDataClassMethod](http://127.0.0.1:8081/rest/Company/myDataClassMethod)

Update: add type "**any**" to ds solves the problem. It appears

```
this.wakanda.getCatalog().then(ds:any => { 
    ds['Company'].myDataClassMethod().then(result => {
        //Work with Result Here
    }); 
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I can call my data class method on the backend, the scope is set to public and I can access directly via REST. I want to call that method on the mobile side, and I don't know the syntax.

Comment: The syntax in your question seems correct to me. Did you get any return in "result" at all?

Comment: I try ds['Company'].method['myDataClassMethod'].then(function (result =>{ but it won't work.

Comment: You had the syntax correct in your question. It should look like this: `this.wakanda.getCatalog().then(ds => {
        ds['Company'].myDataClassMethod().then(result => {
           
        });
    });`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, that's what I thought, but it doesn't work. I have the following message: "Property 'myDataClassMethod() does not exist on type 'DataClass'.". Yet this method exist and is a part of the DataClass Company, I can call it on the backend and it works, but not on the mobile side.

Comment: I come to see in the little button help of wakanda's models, it tells: "A public on server datastore class method can be used only server-side.". So what I want to do is not achievable ?

Comment: Since you can access myDataClassMethod() via REST, it should be public. However, just to be sure, can you check if you defined method scope to "public"? If not, please add this line after the method definition: `model.Company.methods.myDataClassMethod.scope = "public";`

Comment: Yeah the method scope is defined to "public". I can't edit my method locally (on Wakanda). Is this why I can't call my mobile side method ? How can I fix this ?

Comment: Thats ok I find an solution just add ds:any like this: this.wakanda.getCatalog().then(ds:any => { ds['Company'].myDataClassMethod().then(result => { }); });

Comment: Interesting to see that is the solution. Looks like you can not call dataclass methods without specifying the type of ds in the callback. Were you able to do the query after adding ":any" ?

Comment: I try, and yes I am able to do the query after adding ":any". And I don't need the [''] anymore, ds.Company work instead of ds.['Company'] needed before.